# Twitter connect always fail on Parse SDK

Tags: ios, twitter, parse-platform

I have an application on Parse which work like a charm. But since today, Twitter login always fail and i have this error :

```
[Error]: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.) (Code: 100, Version: 1.7.5)
```

And i have this error too on my application actually deployed on the App Store...

So the problem is not the code. When i see this answer : [at first time MKReverseGeocoder: didFailWithError:Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 {PBHTTPStatusCode=503}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443252/at-first-time-mkreversegeocoder-didfailwitherrorerror-domain-nsurlerrordomain)

Error -1011 seems Error 503 which is on twitter doc :

```
503 Service Unavailable The Twitter servers are up, but overloaded with requests. Try again later.
```

Anybody have encounter this issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Twitter API via Node Twit Plugin without issues for over 2 years. Since yesterday (02.02.16) the App cannot log (OAuth) into Twitter and fails with

```
Error: Bad Twitter streaming request: 401
```

So, yeah, I think something is wrong. API retirement/deprecated?