# MKReverseGeocoder location finder error {PBHTTPStatusCode=503} response in didFailWithError: delegate  iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager, mkreversegeocoder, didfailwitherror

Am using `MKReverseGeocoder` to find the current location in my iPhone app. Now a days the app should not find the current locations. When i trouble shoot the problem i have found the following error response from `- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` delegate. The error message is,

```
SourceCache/ProtocolBuffer/ProtocolBuffer-92/Runtime/PBRequester.m:687 server returned error: 503
2012-07-10 12:21:29.773 Dial25[3046:707] didFailWithError:- Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)" UserInfo=0x264090 {PBHTTPStatusCode=503}
```

I have used Google and found the answer to add `[geoder autorelease];` in the `didFailWithError:` delegate but still my app should not find the current locations.

```
-(void)startFindLocationService 
{
    NSLog(@"Starting Location Services");
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 20.0f;
}

-(void)findAddressByLatLong:(CLLocation *)currentLocation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D locationToLookup = currentLocation.coordinate;

    MKReverseGeocoder  *reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:locationToLookup];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
    [geocoder cancel];
    geocoder.delegate = nil;    
    [geocoder autorelease];
}
```

Can anyone please help me to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am attempting to learn more about geocoding myself and may have found some other references that will be helpful.

1. Several MKReverseGeocoder class methods have been deprecated since iOS 5:
   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008323-AppendixA
2. There were problems back in 2010 with Google only responding to MKReverseGeocoder requests at certain times of day.  I do not know if this is relevant to your issue, but perhaps it has something to do with why Apple deprecated the methods.
   http://blog.aribraginsky.com/2009/12/curious-case-of-mkreversegeocoder.html
3. See Rohan Kapur's solution to MKReverseGeocoder bugs by switching to CLGeocoder:
   [Using MKReverseGeocoder in a singleton class (ARC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384789/using-mkreversegeocoder-in-a-singleton-class-arc)

Hope this helps!